# HIbernate not fetching value where the field is null in database record

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using the below hibernate code to fetch the data from database.

```
SessionFactory factory = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        factory = getSessionFactory();
        session = factory.openSession();

        final Criteria criteria = session
                .createCriteria(CrfEmailDataBean.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(CAMPN_NBR, campNbr));
        returnList = criteria.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        throw new DAOException(e);
    } finally {
        DBUtil.close(factory, session);
    }
    if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
        logger.info(LOG_METHOD_EXIT);
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Inside `CrfEmailDataBean class`, I have declared a `private String crfEmailTypeCd;` field which is null in database. Because of null, it is not setting the record in return list. If I go and enter a value inside the field in database, it fetches.

I tried running the query directly on sql database, the query formed is correct and fetches all the data.

Why it is not fetching that record? and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Post the CrfEmailDataBean class as well

Comment: @StanislavL  Its a normal data bean having getters and setters .

Comment: What's the real issue here? Is your query not working as expected, or saving of `CrfEmailDataBean` instances is not working correctly?

Comment: Not sure why people are upvoting this. Without the entity mapping nobody will be able to answer this question.

Comment: Hi all , I had recieved an answer which I am not able to see now . Based on his suggestion , I checked my hbm file . I had included the said field as composite-id in my hbm file . Now it is working .Thanks

Comment: Please add your full informations to the topic, like entity mapping. Also the solution should be posted as an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383553/how-to-handle-database-null-values-in-hibernate-application

Comment: What about `CAMPN_NBR`, `campNbr`, `getSessionFactory()`, `CrfEmailDataBean.class`? Provide the code, please. Which version of Hibernate do you use?

Comment: You should post your answer instead of adding it to question. Then it will be easier to other to find it.

Answer (score 0):

when you use type properties primitive same, need set the default value, same zero (0) or (a) ( ..)

```
private int number;
private int value;
private char option;
```

if hibernate database ready null, when converters of the Hibernate generator a error

- solution for this never user primitive type
- Or define de default value for properties
- Each other possibility your date not null, this value white
- white is different of the null
- make a test put conditions Restrictions.isNotNull.
- make other test put conditions Restrictions.isNull.
- other test make a method receive int, call send one Integer null

first item

```
private Integer number;
private Integer  value;
private Character option;
```

last item test

```
public class Test{

    public static void setInt(int value){
       System.out.println(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer testValue=null;
        Test.setInt(testValue);
    } }
```